# What is a good platform for an e-mail 'nurturing' workflow application?

Tags: workflow, mule

We need to build an application that sends users e-mails when they've signed up for a trial account. There would be delays of multiple days between steps in the process. Different events would also change properties that would cause the workflow path being followed to change.

I think a platform like Mule ESB can work for this, but I'm not sure. Is Mule ESB suited to processes with steps that should have multiple days in between?

Do you maybe know of a better platform for this?

Answer (score 1):

Mule is not a workflow engine, which I believe is what you need to handle your long running processes.

This said you can plug workflow engines in Mule, like JBoss jBPM or Activi, to benefit from both the integration capacities of Mule and the handling of long running processes by one of these engines.

Comment: That makes sense. I've used jBPM before and it does support long-running processes. It's built-in timers are also suited to creating the delays I need.